# How to put a compliant JMS message type on Oracle AQ with Python and cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, jms, cx-oracle

I'm wondering if anyone knows how we can enqueue a JMS compliant message on Oracle AQ using Python and cx_Oracle, a python library for Oracle Database?

I have to integrate a python application into an environment of Java applications built over Oracle AQ as messaging backbone.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what JMS compliant message means, but you can find a sample program on how to use AQ with cx_oracle [here](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/aq.py)

Comment: Hi @gsalem, yes thank you the cx_Oracle tutorial samples were effectively my starting point but I have not found any information on how to post JMS messages. Actually, I have found that Oracle has an internal representation for these objects, the trick was to be able to instantiate them properly from python. You can have a look to my own reply. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, a small word on how I have generated the event objects.
To make a reliable integration with the others java applications, I started from the JAXB event java classes used in the solution. I have converted them into schemas using schemagen and then converted the generated schemas into python classes using [pyXB](https://pypi.org/project/PyXB/).

The result is that I have a module in python with an equivalent to the JAXB classes in the java solution. In the code below, I will assume that `my_events` is the module generated with pyXB.

```py
import cx_Oracle
import my_events

ORACLE_QUEUE_NAME = "Q_MIG"
JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE_TYPE = "SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE"
JMS_HEADER_TYPE = "SYS.AQ$_JMS_HEADER"

dsn = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))) " \
      "(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SID = MYSID)))"

with cx_Oracle.connect("MYUSER", "MYPASSWORD", dsn, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8") as con:
    event = my_events.my_custom_event()
    q = con.queue(ORACLE_QUEUE_NAME, con.gettype(JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE_TYPE))
    payload = con.gettype(JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE_TYPE).newobject()
    payload.HEADER = con.gettype(JMS_HEADER_TYPE).newobject()
    # HEADER.TYPE must have the java class name
    # have not checked yet how to get it from the pyxb class
    payload.HEADER.TYPE = "MyCustomEvent"   
    payload.TEXT_VC = event.toxml("utf-8")
    payload.TEXT_LEN = len(payload.TEXT_VC)
    q.enqOne(con.msgproperties(payload=payload))
    con.commit()
    print("message enqueued.")

    # dequeue the messages
    print("\nDequeuing messages...")
    queue = con.queue(ORACLE_QUEUE_NAME, con.gettype(JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE_TYPE))
    queue.deqOptions.wait = cx_Oracle.DEQ_NO_WAIT

    while True:
        message = queue.deqOne()
        if not message:
            break
        print(message.payload.TEXT_VC)
        event = my_events.CreateFromDocument(message.payload.TEXT_VC)

    con.commit()
    print("\nDone.")
```

The `CreateFromDocument` is a utility method generated by pyXB to create new objects from serialized representations.

Comment: Well, It's been a very long time that I didn't look into AQ, but there's a [whole chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/JMS-Types.html#GUID-492A0FBA-E949-4065-9425-806BBC0827EF) in the packages guide guide on jms and AQ and a [big part of the AQ on this topic] (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adque/jms-basic-operation.html#GUID-5A5BF079-B078-46FD-A29E-41192DC459B0)